How to test a widget method with mocktail
I am trying to test whether a widget's method was actually called, but I don's seem to be able to get it right.
My widget looks something like this:
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.callSaveData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function(DataModel dataModel) callSaveData;

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  DataModel dataModel;
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        widget.callSaveData(someStateData);
      },
      child: Text('Hello'),
    )
  }
}

and my test something like this:
class MockCallSaveData extends Mock {
  void call(DataModel mockDataModel);
}

void main() {
  late Function(DataModel mockDataModel)
      mockCallSaveData;
  group('Tests', () {
    setUp(() {
      mockCallSaveData = MockCallSaveData();
    });
    Future<void> _buildScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
      return tester.pumpWidget(
        ...
        return MyWidget(
          callSaveData: mockCallSaveData,
        );
      );
    }
    testWidgets('Test widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      when(() => mockCallSaveData(mockDataModel))
          .thenAnswer((_) => null);
      await _buildScreen(tester);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      ... interact with UI, tap the button that triggers the callback ...
      verify(
        () => mockCallSaveData(mockDataModel),
      );
    });
  });
}

but I keep getting the following error
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
No matching calls. All calls: MockCallSaveData.call(mockDataModel(null, test_city,
null, test@email.com, test_firstName, test_last_name, H123, null, null, 1, 1135, +41 79 123 34 56,
test_street, test_username, 1234, null, null, null))
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)

So, it looks like the mock is called, with the right data. The "mockCallSaveData" instance should be the same, it's instantiated in setUp(), passed down to the test and at the same time referenced in testWidgets().
Any help will be appreciated, I have spent hours trying to make it work.

What is mockDataModel?  Stubbed calls are matched by matching arguments; the default way to match arguments is by equality, and the default way to compare objects for equality is to check object identity.  I don't see how _buildScreen(tester) gets a reference to mockDataModel.  Or, if it creates its own DataModel object, DataModel will need to provide its own operator == implementation.

mockDataModel is an object instantiated in a mock utility shared across tests, and it extends Equatable, so it shouldn't be necessary to override ==. Thank you for the hint, however, I think it's a good lead

Fixed it, thanks to a hint from @jamesdlin.
I failed to notice that the instance of DataModel passed to widget.callSaveData(someStateData); was being manipulated.
Right before that call, there was a utility method doing something like this:
void textChanged({
    String? zip,
    String? street,
    ... etc etc
  }) {
    userViewModel = DataModel(
      zip: zip ?? dataModel!.zip,
      street: street ?? dataModel!.street,
      ... etc
    );
  }

which of course resulted in a new instance being delivered.
Now, what I did to fix this, and to make the code in general a bit better, is to add a copyWith method to my DataModel class.
class DataModel extends Equatable {
  DataModel({this.zip, this.street, ... etc});
  String? zip;
  String? city;

  DataModel copyWith({String? zip, String? city}) {
    return DataModel(
      zip: zip ?? this.zip,
      city: city ?? this.city,
    );
  }
}

which allows me to test my widget as follows:
testWidgets('Test widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      const String test_zip = 'test_zip';
      when(() => mockCallSaveData(mockDataModel))
          .thenAnswer((_) => null);
      await _buildScreen(tester);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      ... interact with UI, tap the button that triggers the callback ...
      verify(
        () => mockCallSaveData(mockDataModel.copyWith(zip: test_zip)),
      );
    });

and everything works now.
